# Advanced forkbomb immune to kill signal

Tags: c, linux, signals, fork, daemon

In assignment given in one of my CS courses, we are tasked with creating a fork bomb that is very difficult to stop.

It needs to be immune control-c, control-z, and control-d closing the terminal. It also must be immune to sigkill and signal 9, we have gone over signal handling shortly with sigsegv but that was all. I read that sigaction cannot catch sigkill or sigstop signals.

I also read that daemonizing the process will allow it to run in the background so closing the terminal will not stop it.

How can i make the fork bomb process immune to a sigkill signal?

This is the fork bomb we made before.

```
#include<unistd.h>

int main(){

    while(1){
        fork();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also i am using a virtual box to safely test this.

Comment: You can't make the process immune to the SIGKILL signal; that is always fatal.  What you can do, though, is ensure that even if the original process that kicks off the fork bomb dies from SIGKILL, its multitudinous progeny will not receive that signal and therefore will continue spawning children and bring your system as close to its knees as the limit on the number of processes you're allowed to have running concurrently will allow.  I don't recommend trying it — you'll probably need to reboot.  (Process groups and sessions will be relevant.)

Comment: I am using Virtual box to test the bomb, how can i make the child process not receive the SIGKILL?

Comment: You cannot make any process not receive SIGKILL from a suitably authorized process (e.g. one run by `root`).  If the child process manages to change its identity from the user who created it (e.g. because it is SUID to a different user), then it may attain a sort of immunity.  But if `root` manages to launch a process that sends it SIGKILL, the process will die, abruptly and without any options for reprieve.  The only time that fails is if the process is hung in a non-interruptible system call — which can occasionally happen with NFS file systems that aren't available (but were earlier), but …

Answer (score 1):

Not possible to avoid/immune  `sigkill` signal. Read the man page of `signal()`
it says  **The signals SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be caught or ignored**

and

```
while(1){
        fork();
    }
```

it's not a good idea because you can't create processes as much as you want,there is some limit, check `ulimit`. At once stage when there is no resource it fails(`sh` will display the error message).

Comment: That is strictly only part of the answer, albeit a very important part of the answer.

Comment: How would you suggest i make the fork bomb? i have read that :(){ :|:& };: is a simple forkbomb, would this be a better option?

Comment: @Will: The shell fragment `:(){:|:&};:` is a simple fork-bomb, but it is not significantly different from the C code you showed.  It is just as vulnerable to SIGKILL as any other similar code.  Do you understand what that code (the shell fragment) actually does?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I believe so, i know now that SIGKILL can't be stopped, our professor did mention that it doesn't have to be immune to limiting the process, i think i need to do what you mentioned above and ensure that the child process is not killed when its parent is.

Comment: @Will: I recommend testing that immunity (children not dying when parent/ancestor is killed) with a limited fork bomb where the processes stop after a while (e.g. a counter that is set 0 before the loop and incremented in the body of the loop — or maybe `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) fork();`) followed by a `pause();` so that the process goes into suspended animation, waiting for a signal. You can then send SIGKILL to the initial process and see that the children don't die. Rinse and repeat with different experiments on how to set the signal handling, until you're sure you know what's going on.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ok thanks, i forgot that child processes are not automatically killed with the parent, i will try what you said and do limited testing, i am using a virtual box of ubuntu to safely test this as well.

Comment: I see now killing the parent process only stops the children if it is specifically programmed to do so, i thought that that was automatic so i just assumed so. Now i just need to figure out how to prevent kill all, perhaps by somehow changing the child name each time.